# PHP mySQL Highcharts Json array

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am trying to replicate the following example:
http://theonlytutorials.com/highcharts-load-json-data-via-ajax-php/

In this example the output from the file "data.php" is as follows when choosing `id=1`:

```
[{"name":"male","data":[100,500,300]},{"name":"female","data":[75,550,250]}]
```

I want to build a scatter plot in highcharts. To keep it simple i use the example data. The data needs to be in the following format:

```
[{"name":"1","data":[[100,75]]},
{"name":"2","data":[[500,550]]},
{"name":"3","data":[[300,250]]},
{"name":"4","data":[[510,501]]},
{"name":"5","data":[[654,654]]},
{"name":"6","data":[[878,987]]},
{"name":"7","data":[[600,500]]},
{"name":"8","data":[[300,600]]},
{"name":"9","data":[[654,515]]}]
```

My question is how the MySQL code in "data.php" file can be adjusted to get this outcome?

Hopefully you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to achieve. In your case, you want to fetch all data at once and create separate scatter series with one point from each row. Your code in `data.php` can looks like this:

```
<?php
//connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","highcharts");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$arr = array();
$arr1 = array();
$result = array();

$sql = "select * from highcharts_data";
$q = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $arr['name'] = $row['h_id'];
    $arr['data'] = array([(float)$row['male'], (float)$row['female']]);

    array_push($result, $arr);
}
echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Also, you will not be needing select drop-down list, so `index.html` can looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <style>
        #dynamic_data{
            border: 1px solid gray;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration:none;
            float:left;
            margin:4px;
            text-align:center;
            display: block;
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            (function getAjaxData(){

                //use getJSON to get the dynamic data via AJAX call
                $.getJSON('data.php', function(chartData) {
                    $('#container').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'scatter'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Highcharts - Pulling data from PHP using Ajax'
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Value'
                            }
                        },
                        series: chartData
                    });
                });
            })();
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3><a href="http://blog.theonlytutorials.com/highcharts-load-json-data-via-ajax-php/">Go back to the Tutorial</a></h3>
        <div id="container" style="width: 50%;min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, this is exactly the answer i was looking for. Thanks again! I do not know if it is allowed to ask a supplementary question? But is it possible to get the same output but with the following components:

Comment: [{"name":"1","data":[[100,75]],color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)'},
{"name":"2","data":[[500,550]],color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)'},
etc. Thanks again this really helps me a lot!!

Comment: I have found the solution. Thanks again!